# How to get selected value from json list on java

Tags: java, json

I've list from db and put in json list with checkbox and the value. I need the value for insert to table db. So, how to get value from the selected checkbox in java? Thanks a lot.

#### In JSP File

```js
function refreshList() {
  var collection = "";
  collection = collection
  + " <table><thead><th class='LIST'><span><label>Selection</span></label></th><th class='LIST'><span><label>List</span></label></th></thead><tbody>";

  var isnew = $("input:radio[name=isnew ]:checked").val();
  var string = "";
  $.getJSON('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/master.do?reqcode=refreshList', {
    'isnew ' : isnew
  }, function(result) {
    $.each(result,function(key,value) {
      string = string + "<tr><td> "
      + "<input id='id' type='checkbox' value=" + key + "/></td>" + "<td> " + value
      + "</td></tr>";
    });

    collection = collection + string + " </tbody></table> ";
    $('#collectionid').html(collection);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="collectionid"></div>
```

Comment: Are you using some server side framework on java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `name` attribute on the checkbox.

```html
<input name="chkBox" type="checkbox" value="xxx" />
```

You can get the checkbox value from servlet request object as shown below:

```java
String[] values = request.getParameterValues("chkBox");
```

Comment: This really helpful. Thanks a lot.